# Does claims bag persist across user journeys in different applications?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have 2 applications registered in the same B2C tenant. Both use different custom policies to sign in a user. SingleSignOn scope is set to Tenant level in the SUSI file for both apps. The second app has a user journey that begins with a call to SelfAsserted-Signin-Email in its first orchestration step. This accepts email from user and uses it in a technical profile for home realm discovery which is called by the second orchestration step.
User signs into first app. Then in the same browser, clicks a link to the second app which opens in a new tab. User is greeted to the self asserted page  asking for an email address.
Should SSO take care of this? In other words, should the claims bag and all persisted claims from the user journey of the first app be available to the second app via SSO? Or will the user continue to be greeted with the self-asserted page regardless of SSO?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso#defaultssosessionprovider).

To achieve this, all the steps should use SM-AAD.

Also, does SelfAsserted-Signin-Email reference the email as "signInName" as that is what is persisted in the SM.

Comment: thank you for your response. The account that logs into the first app is a federated account. Since that is an external IdP I had assumed that ExternalLoginSSOSessionProvider is ideal. And this one uses the SM-SocialLogin  and not SM-AAD per the custom policy pack. Should I change this and if so how? 
Yes, SelfAsserted-Signin-Email references the email as "signInName" in the user journey of the second application. And this TP does use SM-AAD.

Comment: For federation, using SM-SocialLogin is correct. And I would guess that you won't get SSO the first time because the two SM are different. But if you login to either app. a second time from a new tab, you should get SSO because both SM claims bags will be populated.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. So you are saying there is no way around the self-asserted page the federated user will see when a link to the second app is opened in another  within the same window?

Comment: appreciate your help so far. Please help confirm.

Comment: I don't believe so, no.

Comment: Appreciate your help @rbrayb